# Form html não está chamando php

Tags: php, html5, php-7

Estou fazendo um simples script php que recebe os dados de login de um form html, só que aparentemente o html não está chamando o script php.

trecho do código html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  Login:<br>
  <input type="text" name="userr"><br>
  <br>
  Senha:<br>
  <input type="password" name="senha"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="OK"><br>
</form>
```

Trecho do código php:

```
ini_set("display_erros", 1);
echo "passou 1";
if($_Server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){  
    echo "passou 2";
...
```

O que há de errado com esse código?
ps: nenhum desses dois *echos* estão imprimindo alguma coisa. O codigo php e html estão no mesmo arquivo "index.php".

Comment: Qual é seu servidor http?

Comment: Apache, httpd..

Comment: Olá joão ja tentou usar o **#** ali no ***action*** como se trata do mesmo arquivo pode se usar o # não precisa colocar o nome do arquivo em si.

exemplo: **<form action="#" method="post">**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Login:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha"><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php 
# Verificar se a requisição é valida em modo post
if ($_POST) {
    # Testar se o campo user foi enviado
    $user = (isset($_POST["user"])) ? $_POST["user"] : "Não informado";
    # Testar se o campo senha foi enviado
    $user = (isset($_POST["senha"])) ? $_POST["senha"] : "Não informado";

    # Mostrar os campos em um print formatado
    printf("Pessoa, %s com a senha %s", $_POST["user"], $_POST["senha"]);
}
?>
```